# How to turn off multiple-record custom field set

Tags: custom-fields

I created a custom field set and initially checked the box "Does this Custom Field Set allow multiple records?". I would prefer to convert this field set back to a single record. I checked the [documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/creating-custom-fields/#multiple-record-fieldsets) and I only see information on setting this to true, not setting it back to false. I searched here and don't see a similar question. **Any guidance on how to convert a multi record field set to a single record field set would be much appreciated.**

Civi 5.30
WP 5.5.1

Comment: how much data have you already stored?

Comment: Nothing of significance, they are all test records. The main issue is that there are a considerable number of fields that I set just right, otherwise I'd start the field set over.

Comment: I would like others to chip in but you may be able to do something like .... remove all data from civicrm_value... table (or drop the table), then make changes in the custom_field_group table, then resave some data to recreate the table. DO NOT TRY THIS WITHOUT FULL SAFETY GEAR